# Botframework v4: Stepcontext Option

Tags: c#, botframework

Hello can someone explain how to use the waterfall stepcontext.Option?
I keep seeing it in examples but i can't quite understand how to use it.
Here are example from [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-compositcontrol?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp)  and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-dialog-manage-complex-conversation-flow?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp).

I am planning to refactor my whole code and would want to use this option if possible. Thank!

```
private static async Task<DialogTurnResult> TableStepAsync(
    WaterfallStepContext step,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
{
    string greeting = step.Options is GuestInfo guest
            && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(guest?.Name)
            ? $"Welcome {guest.Name}" : "Welcome";

    string prompt = $"{greeting}, How many diners will be at your table?";
    string[] choices = new string[] { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6" };
    return await step.PromptAsync(
        TablePrompt,
        new PromptOptions
        {
            Prompt = MessageFactory.Text(prompt),
            Choices = ChoiceFactory.ToChoices(choices),
        },
        cancellationToken);
}
```

and

```
    private async Task<DialogTurnResult> SelectionStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    // Continue using the same selection list, if any, from the previous iteration of this dialog.
    List<string> list = stepContext.Options as List<string> ?? new List<string>();
    stepContext.Values[CompaniesSelected] = list;

    // Create a prompt message.
    string message;
    if (list.Count is 0)
    {
        message = $"Please choose a company to review, or `{DoneOption}` to finish.";
    }
    else
    {
        message = $"You have selected **{list[0]}**. You can review an additional company, " +
            $"or choose `{DoneOption}` to finish.";
    }

    // Create the list of options to choose from.
    List<string> options = _companyOptions.ToList();
    options.Add(DoneOption);
    if (list.Count > 0)
    {
        options.Remove(list[0]);
    }

    // Prompt the user for a choice.
    return await stepContext.PromptAsync(
        SelectionPrompt,
        new PromptOptions
        {
            Prompt = MessageFactory.Text(message),
            RetryPrompt = MessageFactory.Text("Please choose an option from the list."),
            Choices = ChoiceFactory.ToChoices(options),
        },
        cancellationToken);
}
```

If possible i would also like to learn how to pass and get values like this way in this example

```
    private static async Task<DialogTurnResult> RoomStepAsync(
    WaterfallStepContext step,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
{
    // Save the name and prompt for the room number.
    string name = step.Result as string;
    ((GuestInfo)step.Values[GuestKey]).Name = name;
    return await step.PromptAsync(
        TextPrompt,
        new PromptOptions
        {
            Prompt = MessageFactory.Text($"Hi {name}. What room will you be staying in?"),
        },
        cancellationToken);
}

private static async Task<DialogTurnResult> FinalStepAsync(
    WaterfallStepContext step,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
{
    // Save the room number and "sign off".
    string room = step.Result as string;
    ((GuestInfo)step.Values[GuestKey]).Room = room;

    await step.Context.SendActivityAsync(
        "Great, enjoy your stay!",
        cancellationToken: cancellationToken);

    // End the dialog, returning the guest info.
    return await step.EndDialogAsync(
        (GuestInfo)step.Values[GuestKey],
        cancellationToken);
}
```

}

Right now this is how i save the values.

```
var userstate = await (stepContext.Context.TurnState["BasicAccessors"] as BasicAccessors).BasicUserStateAccessor.GetAsync(stepContext.Context);
userstate.Name = value;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What exactly are you trying to do?
stepContext.Options is an object you can send when the Dialog is being called, either with BeginDialog or with ReplaceDialog.
E.g:

```
await BeginDialogAsync(dialogId, sendobject, cancellationToken)
```

`stepContext.Options` is your way of receiving that object over the called Dialog.

For example, in the first document, the main Dialog is calling each child Dialogs and sending them the userInfo.Guest object:

```
return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync(TableDialogId, userInfo.Guest, cancellationToken);
```

And the called dialog is receiving it and casting it into a string as a validation:

```
string greeting = step.Options is GuestInfo guest
            && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(guest?.Name)
            ? $"Welcome {guest.Name}" : "Welcome";
```

You can strip the validation and it would look like this, having in mind this would only work if the object being sent (userInfo.Guest) is not null and can be casted into a string:

```
string greeting = (string)step.Options;
```

Have in mind that:
stepContext.Options; is an object and needs to be cast into the correct type.
If you don't add null/type validation, the cast can fail and your bot can crash.
This is a feature of the framework, but is not required by the bot to work and you can use other ways of sending objects through methods or classes.

Comment: Can i add two followup question sir? What is its difference with " step.Values[GuestKey] = new GuestInfo();"? and if you see the first docs can you explain this line"InitialDialogId = InitialId;"? And why all the child dialog have it as "mainDialog". Thank you!

Comment: You should open another question for those since my reply is going to be character limited.
step.values[valueid] is another method like step.Options but for saving an object value across all waterfall and waterfall steps in the same Dialog.

Like step.Options, step.Values[id] is sort of a bucket, but the difference is step.Values needs an Id and you can "fill" it inside the same Dialog where you are using it.

InitialDialogId is a variable required for Component/Child Dialogs and its value needs to be equal to the Dialog's ID that starts when that component Dialog is called.

Comment: I'm sorry i forgot about this. ill try to open a question about that and send you link here? Thank you sir.

Comment: Glad to help. Of course, no problem.
I'm not sure why I got a downvote, though, haha

Answer (score 2):

@Dante's answer is correct, but I'll make it a little easier to understand:

Let's say you have a `ParentDialog` that calls `ChildDialog`.

If you had the following class:

```
public class OptionsPassed
{
    public string ParameterToPass { get; set; }
}
```

1. Call your child dialog with something like: `await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(ChildDialog), new OptionsPassed { ParameterToPass = "ValueToPass" });`
2. You then have access to `{ ParameterToPass: "ValueToPass" }` anywhere within `ChildDialog` with `stepContext.Options.ParemeterToPass`. For example, if you wanted to see what the value was that you passed in:

The first step of `ChildDialog`:

```
private static async Task<DialogTurnResult> FirstStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
{
    var passed = stepContext.Options as OptionsPassed;
    await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync($"You passed in {passed.ParameterToPass}");
    return await stepContext.NextAsync();
}
```