# Right way of extending and chaining Dialogs in Botframework V4?

Tags: c#, botframework

In my `OnTurnAsync` i am calling Main Dialog in a seperate class. And main dialog also calls other Dialog from other class and so on. Is this the right way to separate and extend Dialog? I each made separate Component Dialogs. Because i have a long flow of dialogs and doing them all in the Main Bot class is messy.

main dialog:

```
public class MainDialog : ComponentDialog
{
    private const string InitialId = "mainDialog";
    private const string ChoicePrompt = "choicePrompt";
    private const string DialogAId = "dialogAId";

    public MainDialog(string dialogId)
        : base(dialogId)
    {
        InitialDialogId = InitialId;

        WaterfallStep[] waterfallSteps = new WaterfallStep[]
         {
            FirstStepAsync,
            SecondStepAsync,
            ContinueStepAsync,
            ThirdStepAsync,
         };
        AddDialog(new WaterfallDialog(InitialId, waterfallSteps));
        AddDialog(new ChoicePrompt(ChoicePrompt));
        AddDialog(new DialogA(DialogAId));
    }

    private static async Task<DialogTurnResult> FirstStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        return await stepContext.PromptAsync(
            ChoicePrompt,
            new PromptOptions
            {
                Prompt = MessageFactory.Text($"Here are your choices:"),
                Choices = new List<Choice>
                    {
                        new Choice
                        {
                            Value = "Open Dialog A",
                        },
                        new Choice
                        {
                            Value = "Open Dialog B",
                        },
                    },
                RetryPrompt = MessageFactory.Text($"Please choose one of the options."),
            });
    }

    private static async Task<DialogTurnResult> SecondStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        var response = (stepContext.Result as FoundChoice)?.Value.ToLower();

        if (response == "open dialog a")
        {
            return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync(DialogAId, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
        }

        if (response == "open dialog b")
        {
            // re-prompt not working btw
            await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text($"Dialog B is not ready need to reprompt previous step."));
            await stepContext.RepromptDialogAsync();
        }

        return await stepContext.NextAsync();
    }

    private static async Task<DialogTurnResult> ThirdStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        // what is the best way to end this?
        // return await stepContext.ReplaceDialogAsync(InitialId);
        return await stepContext.EndDialogAsync();
    }
}
```

Dialog A code:

```
 public class DialogA : ComponentDialog
{
    private const string InitialId = "dialogA";
    private const string ChoicePrompt = "choicePrompt";
    private const string DialogAchildId = "dialogA_childId";

    public DialogA(string dialogId)
        : base(dialogId)
    {
        InitialDialogId = InitialId;

        WaterfallStep[] waterfallSteps = new WaterfallStep[]
         {
            FirstStepAsync,
            SecondStepAsync,
            ContinueStepAsync,
            ThirdStepAsync,
         };
        AddDialog(new WaterfallDialog(InitialId, waterfallSteps));
        AddDialog(new ChoicePrompt(ChoicePrompt));
        AddDialog(new DialogA_child(DialogAchildId));
    }

    private static async Task<DialogTurnResult> FirstStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        return await stepContext.PromptAsync(
            ChoicePrompt,
            new PromptOptions
            {
                Prompt = MessageFactory.Text($"Here are your choices:"),
                Choices = new List<Choice>
                    {
                        new Choice
                        {
                            Value = "Open Dialog A_Child",
                        },
                        new Choice
                        {
                            Value = "Open Dialog B_Child",
                        },
                    },
                RetryPrompt = MessageFactory.Text($"Please choose one of the options."),
            });
    }

    private static async Task<DialogTurnResult> SecondStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        var response = (stepContext.Result as FoundChoice)?.Value.ToLower();

        if (response == "open dialog a_child")
        {
            return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync(DialogAchildId, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
        }

        if (response == "open dialog b_child")
        {
            await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text($"Dialog B_child is not ready need to reprompt previous step."));
            await stepContext.RepromptDialogAsync();
        }

        return await stepContext.NextAsync();
    }

    private static async Task<DialogTurnResult> ContinueStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text($"should continue when dialog Achild closed."));
        await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text($""));
        await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text($"will close dialog A."));
        return await stepContext.EndDialogAsync();
    }

    private static async Task<DialogTurnResult> ThirdStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        // what is the best way to end this?
        // return await stepContext.ReplaceDialogAsync(InitialId);
        return await stepContext.EndDialogAsync();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the exception of the issue pointed out in [your other issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54849945/botframework-v4-repromptdialogasync-not-working), yes, you're going about complex dialog flow correctly.

It is far easier to manage a complex dialog flow by doing exactly what you're doing: having a main dialog class and then using `if` statements to branch into other dialogs. You may also want to consider using `switch` statements, especially if you might branch in more than two directions.

#### Good References

[Advanced dialog flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-dialog-manage-complex-conversation-flow?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp) - General guidelines

[Creating reusable dialogs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-compositcontrol?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp) - General guidelines

[What each method of `stepContext` does](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.dialogs.dialogcontext?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable#methods), in relation to dialogs - so you know what to call to accomplish what you want

[Prompt Validation Sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/10.prompt-validations) - For integrating prompt validations, if necessary

Comment: Thank you sir it is clear to me now. Could you also teach me about passing values? Right now i am just calling the accessors everytime and i feel like it is "hard coded". I see some samples like the one you gave me about `stepcontext.Options` and something like this `step.Values[GuestKey] = new GuestInfo();`. Do you mind teaching me about them?

Comment: This is my question about them. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54799332/botframework-v4-stepcontext-option

Comment: I have submitted my answer for that one.

Comment: Oh i did not notice he edited his answer. Thank you Mr. Richardson!

Comment: Mr. Richardson i made a short dialog chain but it is getting a stackoverflow exception. can you take a look? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54885861/stackoverflow-exception-in-a-simple-dialog-in-botframework-v4

Comment: It is because it has many upvotes. But i did not understand it so much and not solve my problem.

Comment: I thought so. I'll have an answer up there shortly.

Comment: Thank you so much sir Mr.richardson. I will be able to check it later about after 2 hours.